# x=math.fmod(c,m) OverflowError: int too large to convert to float

Tags: python

This is formula a^b=c (mod m)
a=122 b=177 m=197 c=?

This is Python code;

```
a=int(input("Lütfen üssünü almak istediğiniz sayıyı giriniz: "))

b=int(input("Lütfen sayının üssü değerini giriniz: "))

m=int(input("Lütfen hesaplanacak Mod değerini giriniz: "))

import math

c=a**b

x=math.fmod(c,m)

print(x)
```

But I get an error. can you help me?

```
x=math.fmod(c,m)
OverflowError: int too large to convert to float
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since integer arithmetic in Python never overflows, you could use the integer modulus operator (`%`) instead of `fmod()`:

```
print ((122**177) % 197)
```

However, it is possible that whomever assigned this problem to you wants you to apply this property of modulus arithmetic:

```
(x * y) % m == ((x % m) * y) % m
```

So, if we apply the modulus operator often enough, we won't overflow, even in programming languages with finite integers:

```
product = 1
for i in range(177):
    product = (product * 122)%197
print product
```